# How to run C++ on sublime text 2 on a mac?

Tags: c++, macos, compiler-errors, sublimetext2

I tried to run hello world in C++ on sublime text 2 on my mac.

I typed

```
#include "iostream"

 int main()
 {
   cout<<"Hello WOrld";
   return (0);
 }
```

but it gives me an error

```
/Users/chiragchaplot/q2.cpp:5:2: error: use of undeclared identifier 'cout'; did you mean 'std::cout'?
        cout<<"Hello World";
        ^~~~
        std::cout
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/iostream:50:33: note: 'std::cout' declared here
extern _LIBCPP_FUNC_VIS ostream cout;
                                ^
1 error generated.
[Finished in 0.4s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: Side note, but you may want to use `#include <iostream>` instead of `#include "iostream"`, since using quotes for system includes works here but may be compiler dependent.

Answer (score 3):

The following methods will solve your problem:

---

**Method 1** : (BAD PRACTICE)

Adding the following line before main function.

```
using namespace std;
```

So your code will now become:

```
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

int main(){
   cout << "Hello WOrld";
   return (0);
}
```

---

**Method 2** : (GOOD PRACTICE)

You can simply write `std::cout` instead of `cout`.

Full code with `std::cout`

```
#include "iostream"

int main(){
   std :: cout << "Hello WOrld";
   return (0);
}
```

This tells the compiler that the `cout` identifier comes from the `std` namespace.

---

**Method 2 is better than Method 1.** Further reading : [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice#)

---

For more information on namespaces, check out the following links:

1. [Namespaces Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace)
2. [Interesting Q/A @cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/49748/)
3. [Interesting Q/A @devshed.com](http://forums.devshed.com/programming-42/using-std-namespace-mean-45679.html)
4. [Tutorials Point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_namespaces.htm)

Comment: ...or, as the compiler message points out, just replace `cout` with `std::cout` to explicitly point out where to find it.

Comment: The first part of the answer is bad practice and is wrong(you do not need to add that line for the program to work, you simply need to add std:: before cout). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice.

Comment: Yes it is a bad practice but a beginner needs to know that as well.

Comment: @CrystalMeth Prey tell, Why does a beginner need to be taught bad practice?

Comment: @const_ref: He is not supposed to be taught a bad practice, just told that it exists. Anyways, I have included your point in my answer as well.